# Mail not sent: sendgrid on heroku using Ruby on Rails

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

I'm attempting to send mail from ruby on rails app on heroku via sendgrid.
This is a standalone app only trying to send an test e-mail. I get no errors but the mail is not sent. Your help is appreciated.

```
== config/environment.rb === 
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = { 
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'], 
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'], 
    :domain => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN'], 
    :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net", 
    :port => 587, 
    :authentication => :plain, 
} 
===

==== config/environments/production.rb === 
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp 
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true 
=====

== app/models/notifier.rb == 
    class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base

    include SendGrid 

    default from: "abc@yahoo.com" 
    #sendgrid_category :use_subject_lines 
    #sengrid_enable :ganalytics, :opentrack

    def test_notification 
      mail(:to => "xyz@gmail.com", :subject => "mail from heroku") 
      puts("Sent mail from notifier") 
   end 

   end 
========
```

I tried running the test_notification method from heroku console

```
>> Notifier.test_notification
```

(This prints out some log info..)

```
#<Mail:Message:279922420, Multipart: false, Headers: <from.., To, Subject, etc).
```

But send_grid doesn't report any mail sent out from my account. Not do I receive the e-mail.

I have also tried to send mail by an other means by calling test_notification from /home/index/controller which will be sent when visiting the home page of the app.

```
=== 
class HomeController < ApplicationController 
def index 
Notifier.test_notification() 
end

end

===
```

Stats don't report the mail as sent either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
DS

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I think the integration is just broken. I've written support. We'll see how that goes.

Comment: were you guys able to figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

try

```
Notifier.test_notification.deliver
```

you need to call the `deliver` method on your method to actually send the message.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a SendGrid add-on to your Heroku.To the code

```
user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'], 
:password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'], 
:domain => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN'],
```

the details should be your sendgrid username,password and domain

Comment: is domain necessary? What does that do?